# PowerPoint displays TWO MsgBox concurrently

Tags: vba, ribbon, powerpoint

Weird behavior when loading an addin from the Developer | AddIns ribbon...

Observed the add-in's Auto_Open procedure fires first, but WHILE that message box is displayed (which should under normal circumstances pause execution awaiting user input -- dismissal of the MsgBox), the ribbon's onLoad event also fires (apparently upon clicking anywhere in the first message box), displaying another message box concurrently!

[image]

Have you ever seen TWO message boxes displayed at the same time? These are not userforms displayed modelessly, they are simple MsgBox prompts.

What could explain this behavior? And what can prevent it?

Oddly enough, once the Add-in is loaded, the events fire with what I would consider "normal" sequential order: first the Auto_open, and then the onLoad, but only after you have dismissed the first msgbox.

Ribbon OnLoad procedure:

```
'This procedure hooks to the ChartBuilder_PPT Add-in menu
Option Private Module
Option Explicit
Private rib As IRibbonUI
''Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    MsgBox "RibbonOnLoad"
    Set rib = ribbon
    'Call UPDATE(rib)
End Sub
```

In another module,

```
Option Explicit
Const AddInName As String = "ChartBuilder_PPT.ppam"
Const ShortName As String = "ChartBuilder_PPT"
Sub Auto_Open()
    MsgBox "Auto_Open"
    Call UnloadCB
End Sub
Sub Auto_Close()
    Call UnloadCB
End Sub
Sub UnloadCB()

If AddInExists Then
    Application.AddIns(ShortName).Loaded = msoFalse
Else

End If
Function AddInExists() As Boolean
Dim a As AddIn
    For Each a In Application.AddIns
        If a.Name = ShortName Then
            AddInExists = True
            a.AutoLoad = msoCTrue
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I'm curious if this will force it to wait: `returned = MsgBox("Auto_Open", vbSystemModal)`  Maybe the add-in loader is firing a separate thread and this will prevent it.

Comment: @PortlandRunner i might try that just out of curiosity. I feel like it has something to do with the *ribbon* rather than the messagebox itself. This is not even a "real" problem for me, I only observed it when testing to determine *which* event of `onLoad` or `Auto_Open` fires first (I needed for another complicated reason...).